# How to see individual events in GA4 reporting (or universal if I can't do it in ga4)

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, analytics-events

I have a conversion event in GA4 called "outgoing clicks" to track outgoing clicks. By clicking on "engagement->conversions" I can see that the event is working and I can group them by source or by some other method. What I can't do is just see the events as rows. What I want is just to see essentially a flat table where each event is a row that looks like this:

```
event_action  event_category  event_label timestamp
{action}  {category} {label} 7/27/2021 10:34:33
{action}  {category} {label} 7/27/2021 10:35:00
{action}  {category} {label} 7/27/2021 10:36:11
{action}  {category} {label} 7/27/2021 10:37:55
{action}  {category} {label} 7/27/2021 10:38:44
```

What's the best way to do this? Why is this so hard? It'd seem like the most common use case for this data would be to want to see them as rows.

Comment: Out of the box, GA won't give you anything deeper than a timestamp down to the hour. And then it will aggregate everything. You might be able to connect it to a BigQuery project and get more granular timestamps but that is a bit more involved...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  In general, Google Analytics is not a logging service.  It doesn't show lists with timestamps anywhere that I know of.   Instead it show aggregate data over a time period.